# grep returns "<regular expression>" No such file or directory

Tags: regex, shell, grep, quoting

I have the following regular expression to match a phone number. The regular expression works `(123)123-123`, but I am puzzled by the last result.

```
user@host: grep -l -v -f *.txt -E "(\d{3})-\d{3}-\d{3}"
f2.txt
f3.txt
f4.txt
grep: (\d{3})-\d{3}-\d{3}: No such file or directory
```

Why is `grep` searching the regular expression?

Here is the `ls`:

```
user@host:/tmp# ls
f1.txt  f2.txt  f3.txt  f4.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grep usage is

```
grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
```

Your command expands to

```
grep -l -v -f f1.txt f2.txt f3.txt f4.txt -E "(\d{3})-\d{3}-\d{3}"
```

which is equivalent to

```
grep -f f1.txt -l -v -E f2.txt f3.txt f4.txt "(\d{3})-\d{3}-\d{3}"
```

which is "use the file `f1.txt` as a file containing patterns, and search the files `f2.txt`, `f3.txt`, `f4.txt` and `(\d{3})-\d{3}-\d{3}`. Apply options `-l`, `-v` and `-E` everywhere."

Maybe you meant

```
grep -l -v -E "(\d{3})-\d{3}-\d{3}" *.txt
```

instead?

The [relevant part of the man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control) reads as follows:

> `-f FILE`, `--file=FILE`
>   Obtain patterns from *`FILE`*, one per line. If this option is used multiple times or is combined with the `-e` (`--regexp`) option, search for all patterns given. The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.

Side note: if you use `-E`, you have to escape literal parentheses. Also, `\d` is not supported as far as I can tell, so you'd have to use either

```
grep -P '\(\d{3}\)-\d{3}-\d{3}'
```

or

```
grep -E '\([[:digit:]]{3}\)-[[:digit:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{3}'
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I learned a few things.